Selecting all array indices with certain objects each for creating a CSV Table in Power Automate
I want to make a csv table from an array variable var_SendJson, which is a result of appending several rows of a JSON output which matched a personal criteria. The shape of the resulting array looks something like this:
[
  {
    "ID": 0
    "Title": "abc123"
    "Type": {
      "Id": 0
      "Value": "Type A"
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": 3
    "Title": "abc123"
    "Type": {
      "Id": 1
      "Value": "Type B"
    }
  },
  ...
]

I want to construct a csv table that looks like:
Title,   Type
abc123,  Type A
abc123,  Type B

Which can then be easily converted into an Excel file.
Image of the current Create CSV Block I've tried using
How do I append the variables here so that I get all the values of var_SendJson[# all values instead of only index 0]['Title'] for all the rows?
Thank you in advance to anyone who is reading this!
- GP

You need to manually define your fields in the CSV step ...

This is the code view of the Create CSV table step ...
{
  "type": "Table",
  "inputs": {
    "from": "@variables('Array Data')",
    "format": "CSV",
    "columns": [
      {
        "header": "Title",
        "value": "@item()['Title']"
      },
      {
        "header": "Type",
        "value": "@item()['Type']['Value']"
      }
    ]
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Initialize_Array_Data": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}

I defined two fields with the following expressions ...
Title = item()['Title']
Type = item()['Type']['Value']

Using item() is an automatic way to reference each item in the array that you're creating the CSV table from.
If you find that properties don’t exist at times, you can use the ? notation to stop it from erroring when referring to the property, e.g.
item()?['Title']


Thank you so much! I've been looking up the internet for hours and couldn't find how to do it this way as. You saved me some good amount of working hours! Just an additional question if you don't mind, would you perhaps know if there is a way to ignore a 'property not found' error? As sometimes my JSON array could be inconsistent, and sometimes  e.g not contain the "Title": property at all, and I want to make it write blank in the csv for this case

I’ll update my answer

Thanks for the additional info + clarification! Greatly appreciated!
